# Multithreaded program runs while loop extra times

Tags: c, multithreading, while-loop, pthreads, mutex

I am working on a homework assignment where I have to write a multithreaded linux program in C to solve the producer-consumer problem for an Operating Systems class. In my code I have a `while` loop that is inside a function run by a single thread. In that function I have an increment to a variable which is protected with a `mutex`.

The problem is that sometimes, the `while` loop will run an extra time than what I expect. For example when I expect the loop to execute `16` times, it will SOMETIMES execute `17` times. I cannot figure out the reason for this bug but it seems to be related to threads. I have minimized my code with the problem still being reproducible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int numItems = 16;
pthread_t threadID;
pthread_t threadID2;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

pthread_attr_t attr;


void *produce(void *param);

int numItemsProduced = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    // Initialize mutex.
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "An error occured while initializing mutex!");
    }

    pthread_create(&threadID, &attr, produce, NULL);

    pthread_create(&threadID2, &attr, produce, NULL);

    pthread_join(threadID, NULL);
    pthread_join(threadID2, NULL);


    printf("Finished.\n");
}


void *produce(void *param)
{
    printf("In thread.\n");
    while (numItemsProduced < numItems)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("Current while loop is at int %d\n", numItemsProduced);

        numItemsProduced++;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Why does the `while` loop sometimes execute an extra time? I believe that I am using the `mutex` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line

```
while (numItemsProduced < numItems)
```

There is no thread safety in this line as you have not locked the mutex yet.
You should lock the mutex for checking the condition and updating the value.

can be rewritten as:

```
while (1)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (numItemsProduced >= numItems)
    {
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
         break;
    }
    printf("Current while loop is at int %d\n", numItemsProduced);

    numItemsProduced++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

or if using c++:

```
struct LockGuard
{
     LockGuard(pthread_mutex_t* mutex) : _pmutex(mutex) 
     { 
         pthread_mutex_lock(_pmutex);
     };

     ~LockGuard() 
     { 
          pthread_mutex_unlock(_pmutex);
     }
   private:
     LockGuard(const LockGuard&); // or use c++0x ` = delete`

     pthread_mutex_t* _pmutex;
};

while (true)
{
    LockGuard(&mutex);
    if (numItemsProduced >= numItems)
    {
         break;
    }
    printf("Current while loop is at int %d\n", numItemsProduced);

    numItemsProduced++;
}
```

Comment: Would the `break;` statement skip over `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);` and cause a deadlock?

Comment: Would removing the `break;` statement and leaving the `if` block blank prevent deadlock? I don't really understand RAII and don't feel comfortable using it.

Comment: If you remove the break from if the thread would never exit the function. If you really feel uncomfortable using RAII, you can just add onother unlock inside the if before the break, but you should learn RAII, it is a very important concept, it will ensure you always release a resource (and can be useful in other cases as well).

Comment: If you're going to write c++ answers to c questions, you should at least mention it.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is caused by thread waiting for the mutex after entering the while loop. you need to check the condition again after entering the critical code:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if (numItemsProduced < numItems){
    printf("Current while loop is at int %d\n", numItemsProduced);
    numItemsProduced++;
}

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void *produce(void *param)
{
    printf("In thread.\n");
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(numItemsProduced >= numItems){
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        }
        printf("Current while loop is at int %d\n", numItemsProduced);

        numItemsProduced++;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```